# LinkedIn share url without javascript?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've read the docs here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin

But even their example url at the bottom of the page just loads a spinner.

Does anyone know how to successfully create a LinkedIn share url?

Comment: The example at the bottom of the page is working for me. Maybe you need to logged in, to get to work.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bqj05y/) which has a working example.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426752/linkedin-share-post-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426752/linkedin-share-post-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn Share Post URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426752/linkedin-share-post-url)

Answer (score 10):

I've tried using the following endpoint and query string and it worked: https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http://www.myurl.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have regularly-maintained and updated URLs of this stuff, you should import a package from a github project or some other project that's active.

Yes, long ago, circa 2010, you could use this URL...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url={url}
```

And then, circa 2016, you could only use a URL like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url={url}&title={title}&summary={text}&source={provider}
```

And now, 2020, May, you can only use a URL like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Wouldn't it be easier to have someone else figure this out for you and just update the URL's as needed?  I have been maintaining a Github Repo that's been tracking social-share URL formats since 2012.  Why don't you check it out?  : [Github: Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls).

Why not join in on all the social share url's?

[image]