# LinkedIn Share Post URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an app that lets people post content to their LinkedIn page. What I want to do is create a button that I can include in an email that when clicked, will send the user to LinkedIn and open the box to share a post. What I would like to know is how to generate this url. What is the structure like? All the information I've found so far is about how to share a link to another website on LinkedIn, not how to direct a user to the share post box.

Example link: https://www.linkedin.com/share?id=0123456789

[image: linkedin]

Answer (score 189, accepted):

##### *First step, let's see what URL is right...*

**2010:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url={url}
```

**2015:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url={url}&title={title}&summary={text}&source={provider}
```

**2020:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

**[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.  Of course, don't take our word for it!  Any of the above URL formats will redirect to the 2020 URL format.

##### *Second step, just how do  you use things like `summary`, `title`, etc.?*

Use `og:` tags in the `<head>` block of your HTML!  To quote the documentation, these should look like...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

##### *Third step, now want to check to see you did everything right?*

That's the easy part!  Take the URL you are sharing (i.e., `example.com`, not `linkedin.com?share=example.com`), and input it into the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  You will be told everything that goes into determining how your webpage is shared on LinkedIn, from `og:` tags to `oEmbed` data.

Here's an [online demo](https://www.sortwords.com) with share links to 20+ services.  Check the source code and you can see first-hand how the share link for Linkedin works!

##### *Fourth step, why doesn't the `og:description` tag work?*

I have a [more detailed answer elsewhere on the `og:description` tag not displaying in the LinkedIn preview.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390562/2430549)

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  I'm a contributor!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the Social Share URLs repository!

Comment: The repository is really great. It is like a dream for new bloggers.

Comment: For anyone having a weird console error on linkedin when using the URL, this can happen if the share URL is not correctly encoded (e.g. not wrapped in `encodeURIComponent()`)

Comment: FYI: Linkedin Share url doesn't work for localhost / inaccessible URLs

Answer (score 60):

From the LinkedIn [developer docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) ("Customized URL" tab):

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn
```

Comment: May be its old thread but can you help me with title and summary. It is not picking up title and summary for posts.

Comment: @ShubhamNigam You'll need to use meta tags. You can then use [this](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect) tool to debug your share content.

Comment: Docs are updated with new API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: You can also use `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=...`

Comment: The URL parameters no longer work, LinkedIn has removed them

Comment: linkedIn share with url does not working for me. Do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: It seems that he sharing/share-offsite on works on some URLs.  When it doesn't, here is an error in the console but it doesn't provide any insight.

Comment: One of the reasons for the URLs not working is the size of the shared site payload. When checking the inspector and providing a link to article where the HTML exceeds 3M, it says `We did not scrape the content because it was larger than our threshold of 3.00M bytes.`

Answer (score 9):

Had issues with LinkedIn Sharing and found a resolve:

Sites shared with Non-SSL (http) addresses will display the error:  "Something went wrong - Try again"

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://example.com
```

**How to fix the  "Something went wrong" share link error:**

Modify the beginning the {url} - replacing the http with https:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://example.com
```

Visit the link to generate LinkedIn's thumbnail and page description.

Both share link addresses for Non-SSL (http) and SSL (https) will work correctly now.

Edit: Replace //example.com with your website

Comment: That's incorrect.  `example.com` is ***always*** an invalid, test-domain.  I'm not seeing "thumbnail and page description" for example.com, probably because it doesn't exist.  And this works fine without error and it's HTTP-only: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://google.com

Comment: That's because example.com is an example. You need to replace it with a real URL but the information I provide still stands. Your Google link isn't a good example because it would have the thumbnail and page description already generated. This is specifically addressing a concern I've seen mentioned in multiple places for developers with new websites that are recently built but cannot get the LinkedIn Share to work.

Comment: Right, `example.com` doesn't work, but `google.com` does work.  What makes you think *"Your google link isn't a good example"*, when it works, and when your link does not?

Comment: Because Google has already been crawled by LinkedIn. Forget example.com - it's a placeholder for 'yourwebsite.xyz'. When a website is initially created - LinkedIn will only crawl a https version of the site. What I'm saying is - a developer who hasn't enabled SSL will encounter this problem.

You can recreate this by creating a brand new website and domain that has never been shared in LinkedIn. Don't enable SSL and try to share it via LinkedIn. It will cause an error "Something went wrong - Try again"

Comment: Not seeing that problem.  I've never shared holdoffhunger.com on linkedin, and it works fine with http-only: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.holdoffhunger.com

Comment: Had the same issue. What fixed it for me is that I used https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect tool first to crawl the page. And after that the https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url} was working. As someone else said, they might be having a limit of the HTML size to 3MB and not being able to crawl the page from the share url.

Answer (score 7):

I found a new way on 2023 to do this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/?shareActive=true&text=This is my text! https://ogp.me/ %23NewPost
```

Comment: Can we have the option to add Image, Mention In Text, and URL.
Please add a documentation link if you have I am not able figure it out.

Comment: "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/?shareActive=true" 
this is working fine, but its not opening recent draft. how to do that?

Comment: @FerozHussain it will open only a new post creater modal only. 
Check a authorization API may be it will help you

Comment: Is it possible to add mentions as well via this method? Tried a bit with urns from devtools but didn't work.