# LinkedIn stripping parameters from the share button url

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm adding a LinkedIn share button to my site. The URL that needs to be shared includes a parameter, but LinkedIn is stripping the parameter from the URL. Any way to get around this?

I've tried using a custom share URL e.g.

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713542/how-to-make-custom-linkedin-share-button/10737122&title=How%20to%20make%20custom%20linkedin%20share%20button&summary=some%20summary%20if%20you%20want&source=stackoverflow.com
```

I've also tried using their share plugin e.g.

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://website.com/?par=1"></script>
```

Neither option is working for me. The URL just defaults to the root domain.

Comment: i tried accessing your url directly and it seams to be working fine.

Comment: What url? The one in the first example? That's just an example to show the format of that sharing option. That's not the actual url I am trying to share.

Comment: Well if this one is working and not yours, that's probably because you are passing invalid parameters.

Comment: Please re-read my post. I'm having issues with parameters in the url that is being shared...not the share url parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedIn Share Post URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426752/linkedin-share-post-url)

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn *no longer* supports those parameters.

**2010:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url={url}
```

**2016:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url={url}&title={title}&summary={text}&source={provider}
```

**2020:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Unfortunately, we will have to survive with only a `url` parameter.

Source: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

But, if you want to show a preview of some site info on the share page, before the user clicks to share it, you can use `og:` tags...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

And when you're all done: Test it with the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.  It's helpful and seems to be correct, according to the official documentation, which is cited.

Answer (score 0):

If you have query variables in your url that you would like to pass across such as `utm_campaign` then you can just url encode that. For example:

`example.com?utm_campaign=li_share`

Becomes

`example.com?utm_campaign%3Dli_share`

Where `=` becomes `%3D`.

So pass that into the share url and it will keep it when shared on Linkedin:

`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://example.com?utm_campaign%3Dli_share`

Just tested and it works (19th October 2023)