# How to share post in LinkedIn personal profile feed?

Tags: angular, linkedin-api

I want to post data from my angular application to linkedin personal profile feeds. I have searched but got only posting to company page but not in personal feeds.

Thankfull if anyone help me out or atleast give me some hints...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedIn Share Post URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426752/linkedin-share-post-url)

Comment: No i want to post text format only and not any URL

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do it with the official API, but you can try with [oneall](https://docs.oneall.com/api/resources/push/linkedin/post/)

```
POST /push/identities/<identity_token>/linkedin/post.json
```

example body:

```
{
 "request":{
   "push":{     
     "post":{
       "title": "#title#",
       "description": "#description#",
       "message": "#message#",
       "link": "#link#",
       "picture": "#picture#",
     }
   }
 }
}
```